# Django Celeryd issue (python manage.py celeryd)

Tags: django, celery

I'm facing issue when I'm trying to start celeryd on my server. I'm getting **TypeError: invalid arguments** error.

**python manage.py  celeryd**

```
/apps/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py:259: RemovedInDjango19Warning: "requires_model_validation" is deprecated in favor of "requires_system_checks".
  RemovedInDjango19Warning)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/apps/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/apps/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/apps/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/management/base.py", line 82, in run_from_argv
    return super(CeleryCommand, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/apps/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 381, in run_from_argv
    parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "/apps/python/current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 315, in create_parser
    help='Verbosity level; 0=minimal output, 1=normal output, 2=verbose output, 3=very verbose output')
  File "/apps/python/current/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 1018, in add_option
    raise TypeError, "invalid arguments"
TypeError: invalid arguments
```

---

I'm using:

```
celery:3.1.18
django:1.8
Centos : 6.6
```

Comment: run `python manage.py help` to see the list of available commands. if celery related commands are not listed then you need to check your configuration.

Comment: It's available.
----------------------
[djcelery]
    celery
    celerybeat
    celerycam
    celeryd
    celeryd_detach
    celeryd_multi
    celerymon
    djcelerymo
------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug with the version of Python you are running. I was seeing this with Python version 2.7. Then I upgraded to 2.7.9 and this works now.